# Next.js getting undefined in console for async request

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Getting undefined for the following code.

**home.js**

```
    export async function getServerSideProps() {
      // Fetch data from external API
      const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      const data = await res.json()
      // Pass data to the page via props
      return {
        props: {
          data,
        },
      }
    }


    const Home = ({
      data
    }) => {
      console.log(data)
      return ( <
        div > Hello < /div>
      )
    }


    export default Home;
```

**_app.js**

```
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
      return <Component {...pageProps} />
    }

    export default MyApp
```

I found a recent answer where it was mentioned that issue may be because of _app.js but i am not able to get the value in console.

Comment: That same exact code works for me locally. I can see the data being logged to the console.
Do you get anything rendered on the page?

Comment: @juliomalves actually i was learning next.js so I was just testing if the api request is getting proper response and I have not added anything to render. This same code was working for me before. Don't know where I messed up.